# Load visible cells in UITableView from SQLite database

Tags: ios, sqlite, uitableview, core-data, fmdb

I want to display several hundred records from a database in a `UITableView`. Though I could use CoreData, I decided to try using a SQLite database since I'm currently attending a lecture on databases. And although I possibly could load all of the data into an array, I want to minimize memory usage so that I can use sort of the same code for another application with more data as well. So my question is, how do I load the rows from the database which are currently displayed in the table view? The table I want to display has several attributes, the primary key is a string - the table should be sorted by this string. So how do I find out, what cells are displayed (indexes) and should I then use `select * from mytable limit x,y` to obtain the rows I want to display or can I improve performance in any way (either with SQLite or with some great code).

Thanks for your help in advance!

BTW: I'm using FMDB if this doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is, in a way, absurd. `NSFetchedResultsController` which is part of Core Data, does all the optimizations for you exactly for displaying 100s of 1000s of rows in a table view.

But as it seems you are doing this as an academic exercise, here are some hints:

- Obviously, working with limits in the sql statement is the right approach.
- You can fix the number of records you want in the array in memory to a fixed number, e.g. 50. This would depend on the maximum number of cells that fit on the screen, times 5 or so (for really fast scrolling).
- You can still tell the table view in `numberOfRowsInSection` the total number of records. It will only request the records it needs to display.
- The index of a row's record in the theoretical array of all records would be represented by `indexPath.row`.
- You keep track of the current offset, representing the index in the total list of the top row in the table view.
- You could write a function that gets the record for a certain index and checks if it needs to re-fetch.
- You can get all visible cells of your table view with `indexPathsForVisibleRows` in case you need to check what is on the screen.
- To make the scrolling smooth you need to override `scrollViewDidScroll` and do the proper calculations of `contentOffset` and set the table's `contentOffset` on the fly to reflect the correct part of the table.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, that's certainly going to help me. I have a single question left: how would it be possible to do this wirh sections? Calculating the number of rows in all the sections in front of the one I want to calculate the 'absolute value' for seems pretty retarded.

Comment: If you want sections, definitely go with the `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: Ok, at least that's an honest answer, I'll definitely do this in a future version of my application, so thanks @Mundi :)